# jQuery get / set value of textbox value in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a repeater with textboxes ID="txtBomName" in an ascx page with a value retrieved from datatable on pageload. 
the end user can change the value, must be not be null/empty. 
I have jquery to check if null/empty on change or blur, produce alert if null then I would like the null value set back to original else set value as user entered.
This does work if, I use the generated control ID i.e:

```
$("#p_lt_ctl02_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneMainContent1_BOM_rptBoms_ctl00_txtBomName)"
```

this obviously only works for the the first textbox on the page, as the "ct100" part of the ID changes for each box. 
code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p_lt_ctl02_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneMainContent1_BOM_rptBoms_ctl00_txtBomName").change(function () {
        var oldVal = this.getAttribute('value');
        if (this.value == null || this.value == "") {
            alert("Please ensure the name is not empty");
            $("#p_lt_ctl02_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneMainContent1_BOM_rptBoms_ctl00_txtBomName").val(oldVal);
        }
        else {
            $("#p_lt_ctl02_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneMainContent1_BOM_rptBoms_ctl00_txtBomName").val(this.value);
        }
    });
    });
```

so, I changed the code to look for **id$=txtBomName** and set an alert to (this.id) the id for each box shows correctly, how can I set the value of the textboxes using **(this.id).val(oldVal);** ?

Comment: you could use a class name for you textboxes and attach the event to all elements with this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
 $(this).val(oldVal);
```

'this' is a reference to the current object i.e. textArea the abouve code will set the value of the textArea

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 // The simplest way is to save the original value using data() when the    
 // element gets focus. 
   $("input[id$='txtBomName']").on('focusin', function(){
        $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
    });

    $("input[id$='txtBomName']").change(function () {
        var txtBox=$(this);
        var prev = txtBox.data('val');
        var current = txtBox.val();
        if (current) {
             txtBox.val(current);
        }
        else {
           alert("Please ensure the name is not empty");
            txtBox.val(prev);
        }
    });
});
```